# Triggering a post to a MySQL on incoming SMS

Tags: android, mysql, database, post

I'm working on an Android app and I need to to post to a PHP form or insert into a MySQL database when an incoming message is received. Some of you may be hesitating to respond, but let me assure you that this isn't a malicious app.

The code that I'm posting below is what I'm using to block incoming messages, except from one number. Would anyone be able to help me figure out a way to trigger a post to my server when the text message is blocked?

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static int MSG_TPE=0;
private String getAddress;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    String MSG_TYPE=intent.getAction();
        if(MSG_TYPE.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Toast received = Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Received: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            received.show();

                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
                    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
                }

                    getAddress = smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                    if(getAddress.equals("APPROVEDPHONENUMBER")) {
                        Toast approved = Toast.makeText(context,"Approved SMS from: " + smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        approved.show();
                            // Message is approved and let through
                    } else {
                        Toast blocked = Toast.makeText(context,"Blocked SMS from: " + smsMessage[0].getOriginatingAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        blocked.show();
                            // Post to MySQL database
                            abortBroadcast();
                    }
                        for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
                            System.out.println("Blocking SMS");
                        }

        }

}

}
```

Basically what I'm wanting to do is post to an external PHP form from within the app when an event is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question.. So basicly you want to post some data to a web server when some event happens?

I see you already have the code to trigger this event so you are only asking how to post data? Here is an example:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("www.test.com");  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "value1"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", "value2")); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name3", "value3"));   
// etc...
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: That seems like it would work. When I place my website URL inside of your example [Ex: new HttpPost(http://test.com); ] the slashes are mistaken for commenting. Is there a way that I should modify my URL to avoid this or must I use an IPaddress?

Comment: Wow. In my hurry I must have overlooked that. Thanks.